# Actionbarsherlock crashes on screen rotation using latest version

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

I'm wondering if anyone can help me. I'm pretty new to programming and this is a little over my head, but once this issue is resolved I think I can complete the rest of my program with my current skill set (I hope). Anyway, I'm using Actionbarsherlock to create a swipe tab interface. The code I used was found on Youtube as an example of how to do it. The URL to download the source is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p91dzt4dekuia3q/SwipeyTabs.zip if anyone wants to look. The sourcecode is available for download, but I'll post what I believe are the relevant parts here. Basically, whenever the device (and emulator) is rotated, the app crashes. If I start the device in landscape mode, it works until rotated into portrait, and if I start in portrait it works until rotated into landscape. I get a null pointer exception as the error and could provide the logcat output if needed.

The MainActivity.java file is:

```
    package com.rufflez.swipeytabs;

    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

    public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);

        final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 1"), Fragment_1.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 2"), Fragment_2.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 3"), Fragment_3.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 4"), Fragment_4.class, null);
        }
    }
```

The TabsAdapter.java file is:

```
    package com.rufflez.swipeytabs;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

    public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener ,     ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
    private final String TAG = "21st Polling:";

    static final class TabInfo{
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args){
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity fa, ViewPager pager) {
        super(fa.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = fa;
        mActionBar = fa.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args){
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        Log.v(TAG, "clicked");
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i<mTabs.size(); i++){
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag){
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "You've deselected a tab", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    }
```

Each Fragment_#.java is basically this with the appropriate reference:

```
    package com.rufflez.swipeytabs;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

    public class Fragment_1 extends SherlockFragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }

    }
```

The activity_main.xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Each fragment_#.xml is basically this with the appropriate reference changed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Fragment 1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

From what I could figure out, doing several hours of research, is that this used to be a bug in ABS that was addressed several versions ago and likely this issue is somehow connected to that issue. Any help would be very much appreciated. Especially if you can provide it in a teacher-student style so I can learn more effectively. :-) Thanks in advance to anyone attempting to help though!

Comment: Note that ActionBarSherlock was deprecated by its author last year, in favor of the native action bar and `appcompat_v7`. Also note that action bar tabs were deprecated by Google with Android 5.0.

Comment: Can this same thing be accomplished on pre-5.0 devices? My devices are 4.1.2 and 4.4 with little hope of upgrade (Samsung) in the near future. If yes, is it called something different? I tried to find something similar in Google searches with the addition of "without actionbarsherlock" but everything kept pointing back to using it.

Comment: I do not know what "this same thing" means, exactly. If you mean action bar tabs, the reason why I mentioned that it is deprecated is because, if you are learning Android, do not use action bar tabs. Use another tab solution, like `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator. Both the native action bar and `appcompat_v7` have action bar tab support, but it is deprecated, meaning that Google would like you to use something else, and there is no assurance that the deprecated stuff will be supported going forward (though probably it will).

Comment: Sorry, I meant like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZN496pmtS8 what he is showing in the first minute and last 30 seconds of the video.

Comment: "Swipey tabs" can be accomplished via `ViewPager` and a suitable tabbed indicator (`PagerTabStrip`, `TabPageIndicator` from the ViewPagerIndicator library, `PagerSlidingTabStrip`, and [others](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/111)). You do not need action bar tabs to accomplish this.